# space between xaxis and barplot in matlab

Tags: matlab, space, stacked-chart

I want to create a small gap between begining of the bar plot and xaxis when plotting negative and poistive values.

Given:

```
barData = [1 2 3; 2 2 2];
bar(barData,'stacked')
hold on 
bar(barData*-1, 'stacked')
```

returns usual stacked bar plot which looks like this (no spaces): 
[image]

and I would like to have a space between xaxis and the begining of the yaxis something as in this example (in this case its not stacked bar and only positve values).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
barData = [1 2 3; 2 2 2];

bar(barData,'stacked','BarWidth',0.65);
hold on;
bar(barData*-1,'stacked','BarWidth',0.65);
hold off;

y_lim = get(gca,'YLim') + [-1 1];
set(gca,'YLim',y_lim);
```

Comment: No. This gives space at the end of each bar. I need space at the origin of the bar i.e. space between the bar and xaxis.

Comment: Then all you have todo is to remove the BarWidth parameters. If you wany spacing only between the x-axis and the bars, you only have to decrease the first YLim value: y_lim = get(gca,'YLim'); y_lim(1) =  y_lim(1) - 1; set(gca,'YLim',y_lim);